# How to improve my AJAX live search by doing less amount of requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, events, filtering

I am building a AJAX live search page.So far everything is working as intended, but I have noticed that I am doing TONS of AJAX calls.

I know where and why this is happening, but I cannot find a way to stop these AJAX calls from happening.

I will try to give a quick explanation and paste the code below afterwards.

On the left side of the page I have a bunch of filters (e.g. location, radius, interests, engagements, daterange, ...). Each and every one of them has an event listener on them (eg changed). When one of those listeners is triggered, I update my query parameters and request the results via AJAX.

Now the problem occurs when for example someone has selected 10 interests (there are 36 of them), and then he shares the URL, it would look like this:

> http://localhost/codeigniter/nl-be/sociale-teambuildings/zoeken?locations=&distance=0&minemployees=0&maxemployees=1000&minprice=0&maxprice=50000&interests=1%3B2%3B3%3B4%3B5%3B6%3B7%3B8%3B9%3B10&sdgs=&startdate=2018-12-03&enddate=2019-12-03&engagements=

Now first off, I will say that I am using iCheck.js for my checkboxes. This means that there's a check on the 'ifChecked' event. 
Since the list contains 10 interest entries, the 'ifChecked' event will be fired 10 times, and thus resulting in 10 AJAX request. Now consider this in combination with 5 SDG's, 2 engagaments, 3 locations, ... and I end up with a ton of AJAX requests. 
As well while removing all of my interests at the same time (there's a 'remove' link), it will fire the 'ifUnchecked' event 10 times, and thus again perform 10 AJAX requests.

This is my full JS code, i've tried creating a jsfiddle with the HTML and all, but the code is a bit intermingled with CodeIgniter framework and hard to place in there. But the JS code is enough to get the picture across.

```
//Set vars available to entire scope for filtering
var searchLocation = null;
var searchRadius = 0;
var searchMin = 0;
var searchMax = 1000;
var searchMinPrice = 0;
var searchMaxPrice = 50000;
var searchSelectedInterests = [];
var searchSelectedSdgs = [];
var searchStartDate = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD');
var searchEndDate = moment().add(1, 'years').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
var searchSelectedEngagements = [];

var getUrl = window.location;
var baseUrl = getUrl .protocol + "//" + getUrl.host + "/" + getUrl.pathname.split('/')[1];

$(document).ready(function(){
    'use strict';

    // Square Checkbox & Radio
    $('.skin-square input').iCheck({
        checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-blue'
    });
    $('.searchinterests input').on('ifChecked', function(event) {
        var interestid = event.target.value;
        searchSelectedInterests.push(interestid);
        updateURLParameters();
        performSearch();
    });
    $('.searchinterests input').on('ifUnchecked', function(event) {
        var interestid = event.target.value;
        var arrayPos = $.inArray(interestid, searchSelectedInterests);
        if (arrayPos > -1) {
            searchSelectedInterests.splice(arrayPos, 1);
        }
        performSearch();
    });
    $('.searchsdgs input').on('ifChecked', function(event) {
        var sdgid = event.target.value;
        searchSelectedSdgs.push(sdgid);
        updateURLParameters();
        performSearch();
    });
    $('.searchsdgs input').on('ifUnchecked', function(event) {
        var sdgid = event.target.value;
        var arrayPos = $.inArray(sdgid, searchSelectedSdgs);
        if (arrayPos > -1) {
            searchSelectedSdgs.splice(arrayPos, 1);
        }
        performSearch();
    });
    $('.searchengagements input').on('ifChecked', function(event) {
        var social_engagement_id = event.target.value;
        searchSelectedEngagements.push(social_engagement_id);
        updateURLParameters();
        performSearch();
    });
    $('.searchengagements input').on('ifUnchecked', function(event) {
        var social_engagement_id = event.target.value;
        var arrayPos = $.inArray(social_engagement_id, searchSelectedEngagements);
        if (arrayPos > -1) {
            searchSelectedEngagements.splice(arrayPos, 1);
        }
        performSearch();
    });

    var searchLocationSelect = $('.stb-search-location');
    var radiusSlider = document.getElementById('radius-slider');
    var minMaxSlider = document.getElementById('min-max-slider');
    var priceSlider = document.getElementById('price-slider');
    var daterangepicker = $('#searchdaterange');
    var curr_lang = $('#curr_lang').val();

    switch(curr_lang) {
        case 'nl':
            moment.locale('nl');
            daterangepicker.daterangepicker({
                minDate: moment(),
                startDate:  moment(),
                endDate: moment().add(1, 'years'),
                ranges: {
                    'Volgende week': [moment(), moment().add(1, 'weeks')],
                    'Volgende maand': [moment(), moment().add(1, 'months')],
                    'Volgende 3 maanden': [moment(), moment().add(3, 'months')],
                    'Volgende 6 maanden': [moment(), moment().add(6, 'months')],
                    'Volgend jaar': [moment(), moment().add(1, 'years')]
                },
                alwaysShowCalendars: true,
                locale: {
                    "customRangeLabel": "Vrije keuze",
                    "format": "DD-MM-YYYY"
                }
            });
            break;
        case 'en':
            moment.locale('en');
            daterangepicker.daterangepicker({
                minDate: moment(),
                startDate:  moment(),
                endDate: moment().add(1, 'years'),
                ranges: {
                    'Next week': [moment(), moment().add(1, 'weeks')],
                    'Next month': [moment(), moment().add(1, 'months')],
                    'Next 3 months': [moment(), moment().add(3, 'months')],
                    'Next 6 months': [moment(), moment().add(6, 'months')],
                    'Next year': [moment(), moment().add(1, 'years')]
                },
                alwaysShowCalendars: true,
                locale: {
                    "customRangeLabel": "Free choice",
                    "format": "DD-MM-YYYY"
                }
            });
            break;
        case 'fr':
            moment.locale('fr');
            daterangepicker.daterangepicker({
                minDate: moment(),
                startDate:  moment(),
                endDate: moment().add(1, 'years'),
                ranges: {
                    'Semaine prochaine': [moment(), moment().add(1, 'weeks')],
                    'Mois prochain': [moment(), moment().add(1, 'months')],
                    '3 mois prochains': [moment(), moment().add(3, 'months')],
                    '6 mois prochains': [moment(), moment().add(6, 'months')],
                    'L\'année prochaine': [moment(), moment().add(1, 'years')]
                },
                alwaysShowCalendars: true,
                locale: {
                    "customRangeLabel": "Libre choix",
                    "format": "DD-MM-YYYY"
                }
            });
            break;
    }
    daterangepicker.on('hide.daterangepicker', function (ev, picker) {
        var startdate = picker.startDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
        var enddate = picker.endDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
        setStartDate(startdate);
        setEndDate(enddate);
        updateURLParameters();
        performSearch();
    });

    if (searchLocationSelect.length) {
        searchLocationSelect.selectize({
            create: false,
            sortField: {
                field: 'text',
                direction: 'asc'
            },
            dropdownParent: 'body',
            plugins: ['remove_button'],
            onChange: function(value) {
                setLocation(value);
                var size = value.length;
                if (size == 1) {
                    enableRadius(radiusSlider);
                } else {
                    disableAndResetRadius(radiusSlider);
                }
                updateURLParameters();
                performSearch();
            }
        });
    }

    noUiSlider.create(radiusSlider, {
        start: [0],
        step: 5,
        range: {
            'min': 0,
            'max': 100
        }
    });
    var radiusNodes = [
        document.getElementById('radius-value')
    ];
    // Display the slider value and how far the handle moved
    // from the left edge of the slider.
    radiusSlider.noUiSlider.on('update', function (values, handle, unencoded, isTap, positions) {
        var value = values[handle];
        radiusNodes[handle].innerHTML = Math.round(value);
    });
    radiusSlider.noUiSlider.on('set', function (value) {
        setRadius(value);
        updateURLParameters();
        performSearch();
    });

    var minmax_slider_options = {
        start: [0,1000],
        behaviour: 'drag',
        connect: true,
        tooltips: [wNumb({
            decimals: 0
        }), wNumb({
            decimals: 0
        })],
        range: {
            'min': 0,
            'max': 1000
        },
        step: 5
    };
    noUiSlider.create(minMaxSlider, minmax_slider_options);
    var minMaxNodes = [
        document.getElementById('minmax-lower-value'),
        document.getElementById('minmax-upper-value')
    ];
    // Display the slider value and how far the handle moved
    // from the left edge of the slider.
    minMaxSlider.noUiSlider.on('update', function (values, handle, unencoded, isTap, positions) {
        var value = values[handle];
        minMaxNodes[handle].innerHTML = Math.round(value);
    });
    minMaxSlider.noUiSlider.on('set', function (values) {
        setMin(values[0]);
        setMax(values[1]);
        updateURLParameters();
        performSearch();
    });

    var price_slider_options = {
        start: [0,50000],
        behaviour: 'drag',
        connect: true,
        tooltips: [wNumb({
            decimals: 0
        }), wNumb({
            decimals: 0
        })],
        range: {
            'min': 0,
            'max': 50000
        },
        step: 250
    };
    noUiSlider.create(priceSlider, price_slider_options);
    var priceNodes = [
        document.getElementById('price-lower-value'), // 1000
        document.getElementById('price-upper-value')  // 3500
    ];
    // Display the slider value and how far the handle moved
    // from the left edge of the slider.
    priceSlider.noUiSlider.on('update', function (values, handle, unencoded, isTap, positions) {
        var value = values[handle];
        priceNodes[handle].innerHTML = '€'+Math.round(value);
    });
    priceSlider.noUiSlider.on('set', function (values) {
        setMinPrice(values[0]);
        setMaxPrice(values[1]);
        updateURLParameters();
        performSearch();
    });

    /** Reset methods **/
    $('#resetLocations').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var locationInputField = $('.stb-search-location');
        var control = locationInputField[0].selectize;
        control.clear();
    });

    $('#resetRadius').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        document.getElementById('radius-slider').noUiSlider.set(0);
    });

    $('#resetMinMax').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        document.getElementById('min-max-slider').noUiSlider.set([0,1000]);
    });

    $('#resetPrice').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        document.getElementById('price-slider').noUiSlider.set([0,50000]);
    });

    $('#resetInterests').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        searchSelectedInterests = [];
        $("input[name='interests[]']").iCheck('uncheck');
    });

    $('#resetSdgs').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        searchSelectedSdgs = [];
        $("input[name='sdgs[]']").iCheck('uncheck');
    });

    $('#resetDate').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#searchdaterange').data('daterangepicker').setStartDate(moment());
        $('#searchdaterange').data('daterangepicker').setEndDate(moment().add(1, 'years'));

        var startdate = $('#searchdaterange').data('daterangepicker').startDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
        var enddate = $('#searchdaterange').data('daterangepicker').endDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
        setStartDate(startdate);
        setEndDate(enddate);
        performSearch();
    });

    $('#resetEngagement').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        searchSelectedEngagements = [];
        $("input[name='engagement[]']").iCheck('uncheck');
    });

    // Set initial parameters (and pre-fill the filters based on query params) 
    setupConfig(radiusSlider);
});


function getQueryStringValue(){
    var currentURL = new URI();

    var queryParams = currentURL.query(true);
    if ($.isEmptyObject(queryParams) === false) {
        return queryParams;
    } else {
        return undefined;
    }
}

//In here we read the query parameters from the URL and set the filters to the query parameters (+ do initial filtering)
function setupConfig(radiusSlider) {
    var queryParams = getQueryStringValue();

    if (queryParams !== undefined) {
        var locations = queryParams.locations;
        if (locations !== undefined) {
            var locationsArray = locations.split(";");
            fillLocations(locationsArray);
            if (locationsArray.length != 1) {
                disableAndResetRadius(radiusSlider);
            }
        } else {
            disableAndResetRadius(radiusSlider);
        }

        var distance = queryParams.distance;
        if (distance !== undefined) {
            if (locationsArray.length != 1) {
                disableAndResetRadius(radiusSlider);
            } else {
                document.getElementById('radius-slider').noUiSlider.set(distance);
            }
        }

        var minEmployees = queryParams.minemployees;
        var maxEmployees = queryParams.maxemployees;
        if ((minEmployees !== undefined) && (maxEmployees !== undefined)) {
            document.getElementById('min-max-slider').noUiSlider.set([minEmployees,maxEmployees]);
        }

        var minPrice = queryParams.minprice;
        var maxPrice = queryParams.maxprice;
        if ((minPrice !== undefined) && (maxPrice !== undefined)) {
            document.getElementById('price-slider').noUiSlider.set([minPrice,maxPrice]);
        }

        var interests = queryParams.interests;
        if (interests !== undefined) {
            var interestsArray = interests.split(";");
            fillInterests(interestsArray);
        }

        var sdgs = queryParams.sdgs;
        if (sdgs !== undefined) {
            var sdgsArray = sdgs.split(";");
            fillSdgs(sdgsArray);
        }

        var startdate = queryParams.startdate;
        var enddate = queryParams.enddate;
        if ((startdate !== undefined) && (enddate !== undefined)) {
            $('#searchdaterange').data('daterangepicker').setStartDate(moment(startdate));
            $('#searchdaterange').data('daterangepicker').setEndDate(moment(enddate));

            var startdate = $('#searchdaterange').data('daterangepicker').startDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
            var enddate = $('#searchdaterange').data('daterangepicker').endDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
            setStartDate(startdate);
            setEndDate(enddate);
        }

        var engagements = queryParams.engagements;
        if (engagements !== undefined) {
            var engagementsArray = engagements.split(";");
            fillEngagements(engagementsArray);
        }
    } else {
        disableAndResetRadius(radiusSlider);
        performSearch();
    }
}

function fillLocations(locations) {
    var selectize = $('.stb-search-location');
    selectize[0].selectize.setValue(locations);
}

function fillInterests(interests) {
    for (var i = 0; i < interests.length; i++) {
        var checkboxId = "interest-"+interests[i];
        var checkbox = $('#'+checkboxId);
        checkbox.iCheck('check');
    }
}

function fillSdgs(sdgs) {
    for (var i = 0; i < sdgs.length; i++) {
        var checkboxId = "sdg-"+sdgs[i];
        var checkbox = $('#'+checkboxId);
        checkbox.iCheck('check');
    }
}

function fillEngagements(engagements) {
    for (var i = 0; i < engagements.length; i++) {
        var checkboxId = "eng-"+engagements[i];
        var checkbox = $('#'+checkboxId);
        checkbox.iCheck('check');
    }
}

function getCurrLang() {
    return $('#curr_lang').val();
}

function getCurrLangSegment() {
    return $('#curr_abbr').val();
}

function getLocation() {
    return $('#location').val();
}

function setLocation(value) {
    searchLocation = value;
}

function setRadius(value) {
    searchRadius = value;
}

function disableAndResetRadius(radiusSlider) {
    radiusSlider.noUiSlider.set(0);
    radiusSlider.setAttribute('disabled', true);
}

function enableRadius(radiusSlider) {
    radiusSlider.removeAttribute('disabled');
}

function setMin(value) {
    searchMin = value;
}

function setMax(value) {
    searchMax = value;
}

function setMinPrice(value) {
    searchMinPrice = value;
}

function setMaxPrice(value) {
    searchMaxPrice = value;
}

function setStartDate(value) {
    searchStartDate = value;
}

function setEndDate(value) {
    searchEndDate = value;
}

function performSearch() {
    $('#stb-items-placeholder').html('<div id="loading"><span>'+res.StbSearchPlaceholder+'</span></div>');

    var searchOptions = {
        type: 'POST',
        url: baseUrl + '/dashboard/socialteambuildings/search/getFilteredStbs',
        dataType: 'json'
    };

    var filterdata = {
        "curr_lang" : getCurrLang(),
        "curr_abbr" : getCurrLangSegment(),
        "location" : getLocation(),
        "interests": searchSelectedInterests,
        "sdgs": searchSelectedSdgs
    };

    var options = $.extend({}, searchOptions, {
        data: filterdata
    });

    // ajax done & fail
    $.ajax(options).done(function (data) {
        var mustacheJsonData = data.result;

        var html = Mustache.render( $('#stbItemGen').html(), mustacheJsonData );
        $('#stb-items-placeholder').html( html );
    });
}

function updateURLParameters() {
    if (searchLocation != null) {
        var locationsUrlString = searchLocation.join(";");
    }

    var distanceUrlString = Math.round(searchRadius[0]);
    var minEmployeesUrlString = Math.round(searchMin);
    var maxEmployeesUrlString = Math.round(searchMax);
    var minPriceUrlString = Math.round(searchMinPrice);
    var maxPriceUrlString = Math.round(searchMaxPrice);
    var interestUrlString = searchSelectedInterests.join(";");
    var sdgUrlString = searchSelectedSdgs.join(";");
    var startDateUrlString = searchStartDate;
    var endDateUrlString = searchEndDate;
    var engagementUrlString = searchSelectedEngagements.join(";");

    var params = {locations: locationsUrlString, distance: distanceUrlString, minemployees: minEmployeesUrlString, maxemployees: maxEmployeesUrlString, minprice: minPriceUrlString, maxprice: maxPriceUrlString, interests: interestUrlString, sdgs: sdgUrlString, startdate: startDateUrlString, enddate: endDateUrlString, engagements: engagementUrlString};
    var query = $.param(params);
    addURLParameter(query);
}

//This function removes all the query parameters and adds the completely newly built query param string again
function addURLParameter(queryString){
    var currentUrl = window.location.href;
    var urlNoQueryParams = currentUrl.split("?");
    var baseUrl = urlNoQueryParams[0];
    var result = baseUrl + "?" + queryString;
    window.history.replaceState('', '', result);
}
```

I tried using e.stopPropagation() and e.stopImmediatePropagation() on the remove option for example. This does not stop the events going back to the iCheck library.

Comment: Search for debounce ajax - simplest is to add a clearTimeout plus a setTimeout on each change of the checkboxes and only ajax after some hundred milliseconds

Comment: @mplungjan thank you for the suggestion! I looked into it and the docs say "Creates and returns a new debounced version of the passed function which will postpone its execution until after wait milliseconds have elapsed since the last time it was invoked." , I don't want the execution to happen at a later time, I just don't want all the intermediary AJAX request, just the 'last one' to be executed. Can this be done via debouncing?

Comment: See my updated comment

Comment: Can you make a (pseudo-)code example ? I'm unsure what you mean

Comment: Add a global var tId; Change performSearch(); to `clearTimeout(tId); tId=setTimeout(performSearch,100);` and only one should run if my thinking is right

Comment: you can add a flag to delay if many filters change so that to search only on last change. Else you can add an extra button eg `SEARCH` which will trigger the search when all options have been selected and NOT when each one updates independantly

Comment: debounce will NOT work here as the problem is NOT with many requests happening on same event listener but with many indepenent event listeners firing one after the other

Comment: @NikosM. thank you for your reply. Can you give a code example of your first suggestion with the flags and delays? 
I don't know how to stop the events fired from for example iCheck (ifUnchecked or ifChecked)
I am aware of the button possibility, but I would like to keep that as a very very last resort, since I'd really like the search to be without a button.

Comment: @Dennis, added answer with pseudo-code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debounce will not work here as the problem is NOT in just one event listener having too many requests in a short amount of time, but with many independent event listeners firing one after the other.

Possible solutions:

1. Add a button eg `SEARCH` which will actually perform the search, instead of this being triggered by individual updates. This is a nice and simple solution to the many independent listeners problem.
2. If you dont want to add a new button do sth like the following. Add a timeinterval with `setInterval` to perform a search with AJAX. And have a flag whether a search should be performed. Then when either listener on checkbox changes simply set the flag to `true`. Also if a request is already in progress do NOT make another AJAX request untill the current one finishes.

pseudocode follows:

```
var do_search = false, timer = null, doing_ajax = false, TROTTLE = 500;
timer = setTimeout(performSearch, TROTTLE);

function performSearch()
{
    if ( !do_search || doing_ajax )
    {
        timer = setTimeout(performSearch, TROTTLE);
        return;
    }
     doing_ajax = true;
     do_search = false;
     // do the ajax request here
     // ...
     // NOTE: on ajax complete reset the timer, eg timer = setTimeout(performSearch, TROTTLE);
     // and set doing_ajax = false;
}

// then your checkboxes listeners will simply update the do-search flag eg:
    $('.searchsdgs input').on('ifChecked', function(event) {
        var sdgid = event.target.value;
        searchSelectedSdgs.push(sdgid);
        updateURLParameters();
        //performSearch();
        do_search = true;
    });
    $('.searchsdgs input').on('ifUnchecked', function(event) {
        var sdgid = event.target.value;
        var arrayPos = $.inArray(sdgid, searchSelectedSdgs);
        if (arrayPos > -1) {
            searchSelectedSdgs.splice(arrayPos, 1);
        }
        //performSearch();
        do_search = true;
    });
    $('.searchengagements input').on('ifChecked', function(event) {
        var social_engagement_id = event.target.value;
        searchSelectedEngagements.push(social_engagement_id);
        updateURLParameters();
        //performSearch();
        do_search = true;
    });
    $('.searchengagements input').on('ifUnchecked', function(event) {
        var social_engagement_id = event.target.value;
        var arrayPos = $.inArray(social_engagement_id, searchSelectedEngagements);
        if (arrayPos > -1) {
            searchSelectedEngagements.splice(arrayPos, 1);
        }
        //performSearch();
        do_search = true;
    });
```

**NOTE** you can adjust the `TROTTLE` interval to balance between more immediate interactivity and less AJAX requests. Experiment with different values to get a feeling for it for your app.

**NOTE2** You can build on this example and make it like a *multi-debounce* function for example by clearing the timeout and resetting it in each individual listener (instead of simply setting `do_search=true` you can set `do_search=true` and clear the previous interval and reset it again). This will make sure only the last update will be performed.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I will try it out immediately. A question that pops to mind, how does this make sure that the 'last search' is performed out of all the AJAX requests that I sent? Since they're iteratively removed/added, only the last one will contain the correct data

Comment: It simply adds a delay before it actually performs a search  so this is how it can be done. it can serach twice for example if there is long time between individual updates, but still it will make less requests. You can work on it for example by clearing the timeout and re-setting it in each listener. This is like a multi-debounce solution. Play around with it

Comment: This works perfectly! Such a simple and effective solution! Thank you very much !!